# About internationalization in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, internationalization, module

I have created joomla module `mod_my`. module consists of `mod_sign_up_courses.php, en-GB.mod_sign_up_courses.ini, default.php, helper.php, ...`
If I write

```
echo JText::_('BACK_TITLE');
```

in `default.php (template),` then it works. 
If I write

```
echo JText::_('BACK_TITLE');
```

in `helper.php`, then it doesn't work.

How correctly use internationalization in helper.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load manually your language file, as explained [here](http://dreference.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-load-language-file-for-joomla.html) for instance.

I quote:

```
/*load language file for plugin frontend*/
$lang = &JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('plg_plg_pluginType_myPlugin', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
```

Source: http://dreference.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-load-language-file-for-joomla.html